# Como puedo hacer para que ingrese una imagen en una migración por 'default' en Laravel 10.8.0

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-blade, composer

últimamente he estado ingresando un atributo por defecto en mi migración, la cual quiero que ingrese una imagen por defecto cuando un usuario cree su cuenta en mi aplicación

```
public function up(): void
{

    $defaultImagePath = 'img/img-user-premt/pexels-photo-8739474.jpeg';

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) use( $defaultImagePath) {
        $table->binary('avatar')->nullable()->after('email')->default($defaultImagePath);
        $table->string('descripccion')->nullable()->after('avatar')->default('Hola, soy un usuario que quiere aprender lenguaje de señas con SignLand :D');
    });
}
```

Una vez creada la cuenta del uusario, el archivo dentro de la base de datos se llama [BLOB - 71 B]

Y la imagen la paso a travéz en la ruta específica y e esta:

```
Route::get('avatar/{id}', function ($id) {
$user = App\Models\User::findOrFail($id);
$image = $user->avatar;
$finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = $finfo->buffer($image);
header("Content-Type: " . $mime);

// Devuelve los datos binarios de la imagen
return $image;
```

})->name('avatar');

Y la paso a la vista de la siguiente forma

```
<img class="img-user-prempt" src="{{ route('avatar', ['id' => auth()->id()]) }}">
```

Pero no se muestra, he intentado con varios métodos y no he podido, si me podrían ayudar se los agradecería...